# RegEX extract image name from serialized PHP array

Tags: regex

I need to capture an image name from a serialized PHP array. I would love to de-serialize it in PHP first but in this case I can not do that because of the current setup, so it must be done without de-serializing it. The part I need to capture is the thumbnail image `Capture-49-150x150.png`

Here is what I have so far using [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/1uW5Gx/2) I can't seem to get it narrowed down to just the file name. Hoping someone here can help me out to finalize it.

This is the entire contents of the serialized array

```
a:5:{s:5:"width";i:472;s:6:"height";i:496;s:4:"file";s:22:"2016/10/Capture-49.png";s:5:"sizes";a:2:{s:9:"thumbnail";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"Capture-49-150x150.png";s:5:"width";i:150;s:6:"height";i:150;s:9:"mime-type";s:9:"image/png";}s:6:"medium";a:4:{s:4:"file";s:22:"Capture-49-285x300.png";s:5:"width";i:285;s:6:"height";i:300;s:9:"mime-type";s:9:"image/png";}}s:10:"image_meta";a:12:{s:8:"aperture";s:1:"0";s:6:"credit";s:0:"";s:6:"camera";s:0:"";s:7:"caption";s:0:"";s:17:"created_timestamp";s:1:"0";s:9:"copyright";s:0:"";s:12:"focal_length";s:1:"0";s:3:"iso";s:1:"0";s:13:"shutter_speed";s:1:"0";s:5:"title";s:0:"";s:11:"orientation";s:1:"0";s:8:"keywords";a:0:{}}}
```

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/1uW5Gx/3. However, doing this with regex is not a good idea.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This works really good thank you. Is there a way to adjust it so that the `Full Match` is equal to just the image name? I ask because the program I am using will only allow me to return the full match and not the capture group.

Comment: Yes, [`\B"thumbnail"\B.+?file.*?\B"\K.+?(?:png|jpe?g)`](https://regex101.com/r/1uW5Gx/4).

Comment: Wow you are the master of RegEx thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

[`\B"thumbnail"\B.+?file.*?\B"\K.+?(?:png|jpe?g)`](https://regex101.com/r/1uW5Gx/4). – Wiktor Stribiżew